# Equating the angle of radii to the length of the arc of a circle.

Tags: spherical-trigonometry

At what angle of 2 radii of a circle does the combined length of the radii equal the length of the portion of the arc of the circle that lies between the two radii?

Comment: Look up the definition of "radian".

Comment: Thanks. Do I understand the correct answer is 2 radians, or 114.6 degrees?

Comment: I believe that is correct.